# python equivalent to MATLAB's 'replace unimportable cells with...'

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

first post, please be gentle.

Everyone I work with is always encouraging me to switch from `MATLAB` for post-processing of data to `python` because of [reasons].

The data that is generated is output into a `.txt` file which is just a bunch of space delimited numbers, in several rows.

My current code is only this:

```
> import numpy
> 
> filepath='data.txt'
> 
> 
> 
> with open(filepath) as file:
>
>     data=[float(s) for s in file.read().split()]
```

I think what this should do is take care of the space delineator, and get me a `list` of all the data.  Then I can use the number of lines to figure out how to rearrange the list into an array (sidenote: should I just use `numpy.loadtxt()` to do this?).

The only problem is that some of the numbers in my `.txt` file are not properly converting to a `float`.  For example, most numbers in the file look something like this `"0.900000000E-2"`, and convert fine. However, a few very small numbers are not written in proper scientific notation and appear as `"1.23456789-117."`  The intended number, is of course `1.23456789E-117`.

Matlab has a built in tool on its import `function` which replaces "unimportable" cells with ____, where ____ can be `NaN`, or `0`, or whatever is appropriate. How do I program something like this into my code which imports the data before I make the call to change all the `strings` to `floats`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). With `loose=True` (the default), it will fill in invalid data with `NaN`:

```
numpy.genfromtxt(file, loose=True)
# or if you'd rather type less
numpy.genfromtxt(file)
```

You can specify a value to be used in place of invalid data with the `filling_values` argument:

```
numpy.genfromtxt(file, loose=True, filling_values=0)
```

To throw an exception on invalid data, you can specify `loose=False`:

```
numpy.genfromtxt(file, loose=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works nicely.